# Is there a way to make Cypress-Firefox testing as performant as Cypress-Chrome?

Tags: firefox, cypress, gitlab-ci

Apologies for the vague question, but I've noticed significant performance (runtime) differences in my E2E testing based on which browser tests are being run on.

`node_modules/cypress/bin/cypress run --headless --browser firefox --spec '**/prod/1-MyTests/**'`

Any advice that results in hitting my timeouts less is appreciated.